# how to delete a row of csv file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, csv

I have a large csv. I want to delete the first line of the file. How is this done? I don't want to copy every line into an array and rewrite them for the previous index and delete the first. There must be a better way. (maybe with fastercsv? how?)

Comment: Not a Rails specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
source=File::open("source","r")
dest=File::open("dest","w")
source.each_line do |line|
  next if f.lineno == 1
  dest.write(line)
end
source.close
dest.close
```

Comment: Wrong, whole source file is read into memory questioner would like to avoid.

Comment: My bad, I read the question too quickly. Here's a modified version reading the file line by line

Comment: You are not closing the file handles. Either close them explicitly or use the block form of `File.open`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind shelling out to a command line, it is particularly efficient:

```
system("tail -n +2 #{input} > #{output}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to another file, omitting the line(s) you want deleted. You don't have to load the file into an array, just read and write line by line within the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
source_path = 'liner.txt'

open source_path do |input|
  input.gets

  open "#{source_path}.header_removed", 'w' do |output|
    input.each do |line|
      output << line
    end
  end
end
```

But, this code require simple format for CSV